# Java setOpaque method not working to add panels over the top of others

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I am attempting to place two panels over the top of another two panels, so the positions match exactly. This will allow me to then paint over the top of the previous(bottom) panels. The reason for doing this, is that I have implemented a "drag a rectangle" zoom function, so on the panel the user will drag the mouse to draw a rectangle, and then the panel will become filled with the contents of that rectangle. However, I have now decided I would like include a visual representation of the rectangle as the user drags it.

Since I (assume) I cannot draw the rectangle on the bottom panel, since it already has a complicated paint on it anyway, I figured I would be able to draw it onto another panel that I would place on top. (If there is any easier way please shout!)

I am happy I have been able to get the panels into the correct position, using a BorderLayout/GridLayout combo, without the need for absolute positing, however the setOpaque method is not working on any of the three panels I have added. Does anyone know why this is?

Many thanks in advance, code below:

```
public void initiate() {
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    mandPanel mandDisplay = new mandPanel(); 
    juliaPanel juliaDisplay = new juliaPanel(); 
    JPanel detailsPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel bottomDetails = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelForDisplays = new JPanel();
    JPanel listenerPanelHolder = new JPanel();
    JPanel listenerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel blankPanel = new JPanel();

    panelForDisplays.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    detailsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    bottomDetails.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    panelForDisplays.add(mandDisplay);
    panelForDisplays.add(juliaDisplay);

    listenerPanelHolder.setOpaque(false);
    listenerPanel.setOpaque(false);
    blankPanel.setOpaque(false);
    listenerPanelHolder.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    listenerPanelHolder.add(listenerPanel);
    listenerPanelHolder.add(blankPanel);


    panel1.add(detailsPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel1.add(panelForDisplays,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel1.add(listenerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel1.add(bottomDetails, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    setContentPane(panel1);
    setSize(width*2, height);
    setResizable(false);

    this.addWindowListener(new onClose(savedJulias));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

PS: A lot of code is omitted to avoid mess, but if anyone thinks they could solve with more code please say! Thanks :)

Comment: `"A lot of code is omitted to avoid mess..."` -- perhaps too much. You of course don't want to overwhelm us with code, but best would be to create a new program, small, that compiles, runs, and demonstrates your problem for us but doesn't have any extraneous code unrelated to your problem, a valid [mcve]. Please click on the link to read up on this valuable tool.

Comment: Maybe you actually want to use either a JLayeredPane or use the top-level window's glasspane, .... or maybe this might be an XY Problem in disguise where the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Please tell us more about the overall problem. Myself, I'm still not fully sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Part of your problem is that I think that you misunderstand BorderLayout. Adding two components at the CENTER position replaces the first component with the 2nd, and so the 2nd doesn't cover the 1st, it displaces it.

Comment: By XY Problem, I mean, maybe your best bet is to do something different such as *not* to create a separate JPanel for the rectangle. For example, [this answer of mine with code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33860388/522444) shows an example of drawing a rectangle over an image, and using it to zoom into the image (a Mandelbrot set image). Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi Hovercraft Full Of Eels - thanks for the quick response. I will try once more to explain, then start working on a smaller program to demonstrate the issue. I have a JPanel (panelForDisplays) that has a grid layout, and two more panels in it (mandDisplay and juliaDisplay). As the names suggest, these draw the Mandelbrot Set and JuliaSet respectively. Another part of my program is to zoom in, by allowing the user to drag a rectangle over the mandDisplay panel, and zooming in on this rectangle. I would like to visually represent the rectangle, and assumed the best way to do this is to place...

Comment: Well hell, then my comment above is more prescient than I had realized. Please have a look at my [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33860388/522444) here and if it helps you, up-vote the answer.

Comment: another transparent Panel on top of it, and draw the rectangle on that, given the coords will be the same, as panel will be sat on top. If I may now respond to your other comments, I was not aware that the border layout did this, so I will obviously have to think of another way to do this. Your code does exactly what I am aiming for, so do you think my best bet is to try and incorporate that into my program? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You were certainly bang on the money - will give that a go, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, adding two components at the BorderLayout.CENTER position replaces the first component with the 2nd, and so the 2nd doesn't cover the 1st, it displaces it. As per the [BorderLayout API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html):

> Each region may contain no more than one component,...

But having said that, as I understand your problem in greater detail, I think that your best solution is not to use JLayeredPane or to overlay two JPanels. The best solution is in fact to draw directly on the image-displaying JPanel. This is not hard to do, and shouldn't over complicate your code. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860388/522444).

Comment: Hi again. I have now tried to implement the method from your code, but I have run into a problem. I think this is because our code differs slightly, as mine paints the Mandelbrot Set using the paintComponant() method, and repaint() is only called when the dragging has been completed. Therefore I think to draw the rectangle as I drag the mouse, I would have to call repaint every time the mouse moves, which is obviously very intensive.

Comment: @T.Davidson: you don't want to do time-intensive code within paintComponent, and I recommend that you do this in a background thread if at all possible. A SwingWorker would work great for this, since it has the mechanisms available that allow you to be notified when it has completed its task as well as mechanisms for easy and thread-clean communication between the GUI and your background thread.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels - in all honesty a lot of that is new to me!! If this is the only way to do it I will research this and look at your code alongside. Many thanks

Comment: @T.Davidson: the problem with your current process is that the perceived responsiveness of a GUI is partly determined by the speed with which paintComponent runs, and for this reason, this method has to be lean and mean, and not have any long-running code within it. And don't worry about new concepts -- you'll get them quickly enough, I'll bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JLayeredPane` to place one component to the top of the other. You can check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

[image]